# HTML / CSS Footer Spacing

Tags: html, css

I've a static site made with html / css and there's a huge gap after the footer . I spent hours to find what the issue is , but I couldn't find . Down below is my Site .

http://ganidu-cyberholic.com/grill/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked your code. The Problem is you have used `position:relative` instead of `position:absolute`. Always remember that whenever you wrapping two elements in the html at that time use `position:absolute`

Make modification in your CSS like following:

```
.dotline {
    left: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -315px;
}

.dotbg {
    left: -660px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -750px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```